# Overriding/fixing TV HDMI EDID with Windows

Tags: windows-7, audio, drivers, hdmi, tv

My Samsung JS8500 TV provides a default EDID with only 2 channel audio to Windows/Nvidia. e.g. under audio playback devices, or the monitor device in the Device Manager, the number of audio channels is noted as 2 and the encoding formats includes Dolby.

I know the TV definitely supports passing through bitstream 5.1 Dolby because my cable box is configured to output Dolby. The TV outputs audio to my receiver and it picks up the passed through Dolby signal perfectly.

This is some default EDID thing. Windows/Nvidia won't output 5.1 if the EDID is limited it to 2 channel.

Does anyone one know how to override these settings? There are some posts on AVS Forum on ATI EDID/inf editing. The problem is it's all black magic and there isn't a good tool to do the job. The best guide on EDID/inf overrides is here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/jj133967(v=vs.85).aspx

The problem is writing a new inf requires that you know what the current TV settings are. Samsung doesn't release inf drivers for their TVs, only monitors. Why isn't this something as easy as editing the registry!?!?

Please don't post links to ATI fixes. They won't help.